# Is there a way to get a photo of the store front from the Google Place API?

Tags: google-places-api, google-photos-api

I understand how to use the Place API in conjunction with the Place Photos API to retrieve media, but there does not seem to be a way to request the photo reference for the picture of the front of a store like the ones Google usually uses in their own search results. Am I missing a parameter here that will always deliver that photo that they use?